# Three voltage sources circuit

Tags: current, electromagnetism, physics

Suppose the given circuit, find the current through the resistant **R2** given 
that:

**E1** = 3 V

**E2** = 4 V

**E3** = 2 V

**R1** = 1 Ω

**R2** = 6 Ω

[image: Three voltage sources circuit]

I tried to apply kirchhoff laws but it was hard given such complicated circuit (at least for me), any ideas?

Comment: Draw in the direction of your current loops and show your calculations.

Comment: What is the voltage across the terminals of an ideal voltage source? What is then then voltage between points b and a. Next what is the voltage across R2. Then use ohm's law to calculate the current through R2.

Comment: @james I just get stuck at the point where a loop has two voltage sources in a row with no resistor in between, I know this might seem stupid but I don't get the way of calculating this

Comment: @Transistor ok transistor I'm deleting this question because nobody seems to be helping :)

Comment: Nobody is helping because you haven't shown any work and this looks like homework. If we were to answer every homework question the site would be swamped. Read my comment again and it might make more sense.

Comment: @Transistor this is not homework this is an exam question that I didn't know how to solve, you don't have to embarrass anyone for not knowing how to solve something, because once you know how to solve, everything gets easier, but we fear things we don't understand, and that's why I asked for a direction, thanks anyway partner :)

Comment: I wasn't trying to embarrass. I was only explaining how the site works. You seem to have got your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the ground node is at the positive terminal of E3.

Therefore, the left terminal node voltage of R2 is

$$v_{left} = -E_1 + E_2$$

and the right terminal node voltage of R2 is

$$v_{right} = -E_3$$

so the current through R2 is therefore, by Ohm's law,

$$ i_2 = \frac{v_{left} - v_{right}}{R_2} = \frac{E_2 + E_3 - E_1}{R_2} = \frac{4+2-3}{6} = 0.5 \text { A}$$

Notice that the value of R1 does not matter (unless it's 0, where you'll short one of your supplies!)

Comment: This is a very explained answer! Thanks a lot! 
Now I see my problem, I just didn't get how things go when we connect two V sources in a row, and it was rather problematic to assure the sign of the Voltages once I add them while going through a certain loop, very thankful :)

Comment: I'm glad it's clear now!

Answer (score 0):

@alexander_yz - a perfect voltage source always has its rated voltage across it.

So the Voltage from b to the juction of E2 and E3 is 2V.
Similarly the voltage from that junction to a is 4V.

So the voltage from b to a is 6V. (the voltages add because the voltage sources are in series and the same way round ,or if you prefer, trace a loop from b to a through that junction, and add the voltages of the sources as you cross them)

now extend your loop through E1 to the junction of E1 and R2. You've crossed E1 backwards so you're subtracting its voltage of 3V. You can do this because these are
perfect voltage sources so you know what the voltage across them is.

So your loop now goes from one side of R2 to the other and you have a voltage of 4+2-3 = 3V.

Now you can use ohms law to calculate the current through a 6 ohm resistor with 3V across it, which should be be 1/2 an amp.

Comment: If I could just upvote this answer. THANK U 
So the existence of R1 don't affect anything once we choose the loop from b to a and then from a to R2 !!

Comment: Exactly. R1 puts some load on E2, but because E2 is a perfect voltage source, the voltage across it stays the same, so you can just ignore R1.